# ajax request returns status = 0 for submit event but works with status=200 for keyup event

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am having a problem with the following javascript/ajax code. The code searches a JSON file which just has some contact names and email addresses in it. When the "keyup" event calls addr.search everything is fine and in the function call to ajaxCall the attributes request.readyState=4 and request.Status=200, but when the "submit" event calls the same search calling the same addr.search function the request.status is 0 and it fails.
Is it possible it has something to do with the action attribute in the form element?
I should add that I am running this on a WAMP server.

```
/* standard Ajax xhr function */

function getHTTPObject() {

var xhr;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // check for support

    // if it's supported, use it 
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // check for the IE 6 Ajax

    // save it to the xhr variable
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

}

// spit out the correct one so we can use it
return xhr;
}

/* define the Ajax call */

function ajaxCall(dataUrl, outputElement, callback) {

/* use our function to get the correct Ajax object based on support */
var request = getHTTPObject();

outputElement.innerHTML = "Loading";

request.onreadystatechange = function() {

    // check to see if the Ajax call went through
    if ( request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200 ) {

        // save the ajax response to a variable
        var contacts = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

        // make sure the callback is indeed a function before executing it
        if(typeof callback === "function"){

            callback(contacts);

        } // end check

    } // end ajax status check

} // end onreadystatechange

request.open("GET", dataUrl, true);
request.send(null);

}

/* wrap everything in an anonymous function to contain the variables */

(function(){

/* define the DOM elements and common variables you'll need */
var searchForm = document.getElementById("search-form"),
    searchField = document.getElementById("q"),
    getAllButton = document.getElementById("get-all"),
    target = document.getElementById("output");

/* define address book methods */
var addr = {

    search : function(event){

        // set the output element
        var output = document.getElementById("output");

         ajaxCall('data/contacts.json', output, function (data) {

            // save the input value, contacts length and i to variables
            var searchValue = searchField.value,
                addrBook = data.addressBook,
                count = addrBook.length,
                i;

            // stop the default behavior
            event.preventDefault();

            // clear the target area just incase there's something in it.
            target.innerHTML = "";

            // check the count, of course
            if(count > 0 && searchValue !== ""){

                // loop through the contacts
                for(i = 0; i < count; i = i + 1) {

                    // look through the name value to see if it contains the searchterm string
                    var obj = addrBook[i],
                        isItFound = obj.name.indexOf(searchValue);

                    // anything other than -1 means we found a match
                    if(isItFound !== -1) {
                        target.innerHTML += '<p>' + obj.name + ', <a href="mailto:' + obj.email + '">'+ obj.email +'</a><p>';
                    } // end if

                } // end for loop

            } // end count check

        }); // end ajax call

    },
    getAllContacts : function () {

        // set the output element
        var output = document.getElementById("output");

        // start Ajax call
        ajaxCall('data/contacts.json', output, function (data) {

            var addrBook = data.addressBook,
                count = addrBook.length,
                i;

            // clear the target area just incase there's something in it.
            target.innerHTML = "";

            // check the count, of course
            if(count > 0) {

                // loop through the contacts
                for(i = 0; i < count; i = i + 1) {

                    // look through the name value to see if it contains the searchterm string
                    var obj = addrBook[i];

                    target.innerHTML += '<p>' + obj.name + ', <a href="mailto:' + obj.email + '">'+ obj.email +'</a><p>';

                } // end for loop
            } // end count check

        }); // end ajax call
    },
    setActiveSection : function() {

        // add a class of "active" the wrapping div
        this.parentNode.setAttribute("class", "active");

    },
    removeActiveSection : function() {

        // remove the class from the wrapping div
        this.parentNode.removeAttribute("class");

    },
    addHoverClass : function() {

        // remove the class from the wrapping div
        searchForm.setAttribute("class", "hovering");

    },
    removeHoverClass : function(){

        // remove the class from the wrapping div
        searchForm.removeAttribute("class");

    }

} // end addr object

// activate auto complete on keyUp
searchField.addEventListener("keyup", addr.search, false);

// set active section on focus of the form field
searchField.addEventListener("focus", addr.setActiveSection, false);

// remove active section on blur of the form field
searchField.addEventListener("blur", addr.removeActiveSection, false);

// get all contacts when you click the button
getAllButton.addEventListener("click", addr.getAllContacts, false);

// add hover class on mouse over of the form field
searchForm.addEventListener("mouseover", addr.addHoverClass, false);

 // remove hover class on mouse out of the form field
searchForm.addEventListener("mouseout", addr.removeHoverClass, false);

// activate search on form submit
searchForm.addEventListener("submit", addr.search, false);


})(); // end anonymous function
```

Here is the html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Address Book Application</title>
<style>
    .active { background:#ddd; }
    .hovering { background:#eee; }
    form > div { padding:10px; }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Address Book</h1>

<form action="" method="get" id="search-form">

<div>
    <label for="q">Search address book</label>
    <input type="search" id="q" name="q" required placeholder="type a name" autocomplete="off">
</div>

<div class="button-group">
    <button type="submit" id="search-btn">search</button>
    <button type="button" id="get-all">get all contacts</button>
</div><!--/.button-group-->

</form>
<div id="output" aria-atomic="true" aria-live="polite"></div><!--/#output-->

<script src="js/addressbook.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and the JSON file:

```
{
"addressBook" : [
{
    "name": "hillisha",
    "email": "hill@example.com"
},
{
    "name": "paul",
    "email": "cleveland@example.com"
},
{
    "name": "vishaal",
    "email": "vish@example.com"
},
{
    "name": "mike",
    "email": "grady@example.com"
},
{
    "name": "jamie",
    "email": "dusted@example.com"
},
{
    "name": "gini",
    "email": "g@example.com"
},
{
    "name": "kristen",
    "email": "marv@example.com"
},
{
    "name": "starlen",
    "email": "stars@example.com"
},
{
    "name": "archie",
    "email": "ie@example.com"
},
{
    "name": "bill",
    "email": "hickey@example.com"
}
]
}
```

Comment: Are you really loading *the same file* again and again onkeyup? You should only do that once and then reuse the stored data

Comment: Yes, that would be much better. I am using this as an exercise to learn Ajax, so I appreciate your observations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not stopping the default action. It doesn't matter for the keyup event, but the form does get submitted (with an `action=""` to the same location so you're not really noticing it). On leaving the page, the runnning ajax requests get aborted and you see the status code 0.

The problem is that you're invoking `event.preventDefault();` from the ajax callback - it's too late then, all event-related actions have already been run. Move it to the first line of your `addr.search` function.

Comment: Thank you that works. You're brilliant, I have been staring at this for hours.